# Basic Hook development length using CSA A23.3 provisions

Tags: reinforced-concrete

I have 8" thick reinforced concrete walls and I would like to anchor my horizontal corner reinforcement with only 1 hook (I have only 1 layer of reinforcement in both walls). The problem is CSA A23.3 (same for ACI if I'm not mistaken) restricts minimum hook length to 6" or $8d_b$ = 120mm = 5" in my case.

If I want to put my reinforcement in the middle of my wall, there is no way for me to get that 6 inches. Can I simply assume that the bar is held by my vertical reinforcement (see picture)?

[image: CORNER]

Comment: `If i want to put my reinforcement in the middle of my wall, there is no way for me to get that 6 inches.`  Not quite sure what you mean here.  Do you mean that you want the reinforcement to be in the middle of the thickness of the wall?  A sketch of a wall elevation might help illustrate your case.

Comment: Also, looking at CSA A23.1-09, Section 6.6.2.2(b), a 90-deg hook needs $12d_b$ at the free end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd agree, you cannot fit a *horizontally oriented* 5" 90° bar bend in an 8" thick wall if you want your rebar curtain to be located at the center-line of the wall. However, there is no reason that the bent bars will not fit if you orient the bend vertically. The bars can be placed such that the 5" 90° bar bend is oriented vertically.

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it.